# Считать файл по 4 байта на Java

Tags: java

Мне нужно считать файл в массив по 4 байта. Т.е. 1 элемент массива - это 4 байта файла. Как это сделать? Или как перезаписать из однобайтового массива в такой, укоротив его по количеству элементов в 4 раза?

Answer (score 1):

Если не вдаваться в подробности задачи, то следующий код может решить поставленную задачу:

```
    int[] result = new int[1000];
    try (
            DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.dat")));
    ) {
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = stream.readInt();
        }
    } catch(EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
```

Здесь используется класс DataInputStream, который позволяет читать данные из нижележащего потока (файла) порциями по одному, два, четыре или восемь байт. Самый простой тип данных длиной четыре байта - Integer, он и используется в коде.

Стоит заметить, что здесь никак не учитывается порядок байт (Little Endian или Big Endian). Но класс DataInputStream, собственно, и не позволяет его учитывать.

Comment: Мне бы как раз чтобы порядок сохранялся

Comment: Порядок, естественно, сохраняется. Тут главный вопрос - какой он, этот порядок. Если в файле Big Endian, то код выше будет отлично работать и можно не заморачиваться. Если в файле Little Endian - но нужно другой вариант думать.